# Mvn strange error

Tags: maven

I am using maven2, java ver 1.7.0
and when i try to use mvn clean or mvn package i have got error :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3000:3000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.PathUtils.port(PathUtils.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.repository.Repository.setUrl(Repository.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.repository.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.DefaultArtifactRepository.<init>(DefaultArtifactRepository.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.DefaultArtifactRepositoryFactory.createDeploymentArtifactRepository(DefaultArtifactRepositoryFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectUtils.buildDeploymentArtifactRepository(ProjectUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.processProjectLogic(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1029)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:880)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:560)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

I am don't know what is wrong because my friend successfull compile project 
so what is wrong ....

Comment: Is this the complete error output i have my doubts.

Comment: Do you know where thos "3000:3000" are comming from? Have you taken a look into your settings.xml file ? Taken a look into the pom you are using ?

Comment: can you run the build with mvn clean -e  You'll be able to see more information.