# maven compiler plugin error at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I try to create a jar of the repo https://github.com/olehmberg/WebTableStitching using the maven compiler plugin but I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:691)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.write(SimpleLogger.java:381)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.log(SimpleLogger.java:376)
at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.info(SimpleLogger.java:538)
at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:59)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
...
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
```

First, I tried to run maven clean compile package inside Intellij

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.5281.24, built on June 12, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

I also downloaded Maven version 3.5.4 from the Apache website and ran "mvn clean compile package" from cmd.

The pom.xml can be found inside the github repo. I already tried to setting MAVEN_OPTS to "-Xms2G -Xms8G -noverify" but I still get an error.

But then I get the following error in the cmd

```
[java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34m[[["
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:867)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiPrintStream.filter(AnsiPrintStream.java:129)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:97)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:107)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.print(FilterPrintStream.java:156)
    at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.println(FilterPrintStream.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Has someone a suggestion how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

*edit*
[maven version Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdFOb.png)

I tried the bundeled maven and the downloaded maven binary inside Intellij.

Comment: The NumberFormatException should be solved with Maven-3.5.4, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6382 . What happens if you run `mvn package`? (package already implies compile)

Comment: The StackOverflowError as above

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:583)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.FilterPrintStream.write(FilterPrintStream.java:99)
....

Comment: I am using Maven 3.5.4 and also have this issue. The solution presented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51840311/7962200 worked for me.